# Updating each row in a table

Tags: database, oracle

I have two tables both of which have a column named column_value which holds a number value. Now what i want is to sum the values of column_value in both the tables individually for each row and then update the same column (column_value) in the first table with the sum that i get for each row.
For example I have table A and table B, both of them have a column name `AMOUNT`.

Table A:

```
id     AMOUNT
1      20
2      30
```

Table B:

```
id     AMOUNT
1      10
2      25
```

First of all i want to get the following result

```
id AMOUNT  AMOUNT TOTALAMOUNT
1   20      10      30
2   30      25      55
```

Now i would like to update each row of the A table with the `TOTALAMOUNT` against each id

so that after the Update the table A should look like

```
id AMOUNT  
1   30     
2   55
```

Comment: Add a trial of your solution

Answer (score 0):

**Selection :**

```
SELECT A.ID,
       NVL(A.AMOUNT,0) A_AMOUNT ,
       NVL(B.AMOUNT,0) B_AMOUNT ,
       NVL(A.AMOUNT,0) + NVL(B.AMOUNT,0) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM TABLEA A, TABLEB B
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
```

**Update:**

```
UPDATE TABLEA A
SET A.AMOUNT = (SELECT NVL(A.AMOUNT,0) + NVL(B.AMOUNT,0)
                   FROM TABLEB B
                WHERE  A.ID = B.ID)
```

Comment: hi. i am having the following on update query..
Error starting at line 109 in command:
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: i expected this, When more than one id in tableB is present for one id in TableA

Comment: oh yeah thats right, for my table B if i have another id thats unique then how can we modify the above query , suppose i have b_id unique for table B.

Comment: Yes.. The join has to be made sure than.. Each record in A is exactly matched with one row in B

Answer (score 0):

You should have to use left join. For example:

```
Table_a
id   val
1    10
2    20

Table_b
id   val
1    20
2    30

update Table_a a left join Table_b b on a.id = b.id set a.val = (a.val+b.val);
```

After this operation:

```
Table_a
id   val
1    30
2    50
```

Comment: Hi, i followed the same query using left join and it says..
SQL Error: ORA-00971: missing SET keyword
00971. 00000 -  "missing SET keyword"
thanks for your time.